# Two or more firefox windows and have distinct sessions in each

Tags: firefox

I'd like to open two or more firefox windows (version 3.6.10) and have distinct sessions in each.

For instance:

I open window 1, and go to gmail.com and sign in.

I open window 2, and go to gmail.com - I'm not currently signed in with this window. So I can sign into a different account.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please expand on the programming aspects of your question? As it stands it is off topic to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can open multiple profiles simultaneously in Firefox using the following command:

```
firefox --no-remote -P
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the second instance as a portable version of firefox.

You can download it here: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable